# Decimal Format, says it needs to be a string?

Tags: java, string, double, decimalformat

I'm getting the error "cannot convert from String to Double" when I run this code, any ideas?

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.###");

    String [] data = null;
    data = str.split(" ");

    Double bat_avg = Double.parseDouble(data[4])/Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
    bat_avg = df.format(bat_avg);
    System.out.println(bat_avg);
```

Answer (score 4):

[DecimalFormat#format(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) returns a `String` so the output needs to be this type rather than a `Double`:

```
String output = df.format(bat_avg);
```